# Owl Carousel 1st item border none

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

Use owl carousel plugin then apply those.
**state-single** div has a border. I want the 1st item state-single border none.
HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel loop">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="state-single"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="state-single"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="state-single"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Normal div it works but with owl-carousel plugin it not works.

Comment: `.loop .item:first-child .state-single{boder: none;}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works for me :)

```
.owl-item:not(.active) + .owl-item.active .state-single{
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: But this takes the active item from the carousel, it's different from the first item ;)